# Draw jquery datatable row based on internal array

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have JSON response from server as below,

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "apiKey": "test1",
        "name": [{
            "identifier": "1",
            "status": "Online",
        },
        {
            "identifier": "2",
            "status": "Online",
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "apiKey": "test2",
        "name": [{
            "identifier": "1",
            "status": "Online",
        },
        {
    "identifier": "2",
            "status": "Online",
        }]
    }]
}
```

Datatable should have two row for id 1.
E.g.

```
ID      name    status
1       1       Online
1       2       Online
2       1       Online
2       2       Online
```

Find my jquery/javascript code below,

```
 $.ajax({
    url : "url",
    type : "GET",
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var data = response.data;
        if( data != null ){
            $(data).each(function(i) {
                var data1 = data[i]["name"];
                    oTable = $("#exampletable").DataTable({
                    "bFilter" : false,
                    "searching" : false,
                    "bLengthChange" : false,
                    bJQueryUI : true,
                    aaData : data1,
                    aoColumns : [
                        { mData : data[i]["id"]},
                        { mData : "identifier"},
                        { mData : "status"},
                        { mData : null,
                            "render" : function(mData,type,row) {
                                var mData = "<a href=\"downloads/"+row.Version+"\">DOWNLOAD</a>";
                                return mData;
                            },
                        } ]
                    });
            }); 
        }
    }
});
```

1) First column "ID" value doesn't display

2) Only first object that is only two rows display instead 4 rows.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do realize that you initialize the table in `each` loop?

Comment: How can I remove that and get the desired result? Also, it displays first record and for the second, it gives an error of table reinitialization.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want items repeated according to the nested array you must reorganize the JSON and pass that reorganized JSIN back to DataTables. Here is an example :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   ajax: {
     url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/n6wrn',
     dataSrc: function(d) {
       var data = [];
       d.data.forEach(function(f) {
         //repeat, insert new "rows" for each of the nested array items
         data.push( $.extend({ id: f.id }, f.name[0] ))
         data.push( $.extend({ id: f.id }, f.name[1] ))
       })
       return data
     }
   },
   columns: [
     { title: 'id', data: 'id' },
     { title: 'identifier', data: 'identifier' },
     { title: 'status', data: 'status' }
   ]
})
```

Do not use your own ajax if it can be avoided. DataTables builtin ajax is the exact same as jQuery ajax, except it provides som extra features and is designed to handle responses targeting DT.

**http://jsfiddle.net/ahewatux/**